# Why does Online Dominion allow you to reveal reaction cards multiple times?

Tags: dominion, online

In the [FAQ](http://dominion.isotropic.org/faq/) for Isotropic's online Dominion game, the creator states:

> No, you really can reveal a reaction card like Moat or Secret Chamber multiple times. They are designed to be idempotent so there's no point in doing so, but allowing this avoids strange corner cases having to do with Secret Chamber drawing other reaction cards.

What, exactly, are these corner cases?  Can you reveal a reaction card drawn from Secret Chamber, or is there some other strange case drawing a reaction card with Secret Chamber causes?

Comment: @ire_and_curses Oh, wow, can't believe I missed that.  Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can reveal a reaction drawn by Secret Chamber.  For example, the following scenario is perfectly valid (according to [BGG's Dominion FAQ](http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Dominion_FAQ#toc19))

1. Be attacked.
2. Reveal Secret Chamber.
3. Draw two cards (one Moat), replace two cards.
4. Reveal Moat to deflect attack.
5. Reveal Secret Chamber again.
6. Draw two cards, replace two cards (put Moat back on deck)

Most reaction cards, such as Moat, have no real value to being revealed multiple times during the same trigger.  However, since the rules do not explicitly forbid such behaviour and there may be other edge cases where revealing the same card multiple times has merit, it remains a valid option.